# MessageBodyWriter error caused by CascadeType

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jersey, tomcat8

There is an webservice running in two systems:

1. Windows 7 x64, Apache Tomcat/8.5.16, JVM 1.8.0_65-b17
2. Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, Apache Tomcat/8.5.15, JVM 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11

The webservice looks like:

```
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, mappedBy = "orderId")
    private List<Item> itemList;

    // getters and setters

}

... 

public class Item implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OrderAdapter.class)
    private Order orderId;

    // getters and setters
}

... 

@GET
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Order> findAll(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString) throws Exception {

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM order", Order.class);
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

Problem: The webservice runs ok in the first server, no errors. In second server i got the error:

> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
>   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class
>   java.util.Vector, genericType=java.util.List

The webservice only works in second server if I change the line:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH}, mappedBy = "orderId")
```

To:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderId")
```

So, why the same webservice runs ok in first server and causes error in second? And what is relation with MessageBodyWriter and CascadeType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having problems with cache, I realized there were 2 persistence libs in project:

- persistence-api-1.0.jar
- javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar

So I guess it works in one server because of loading order. Removing first one solved problem.